# Look Up Transform error in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have issue,
I am trying to Look Up data using SSIS, 
Let Say I have 2 Tables.

1. Master Store (ID, store_code, store_name)
2. SalesDW (store_code, qty_sold)

And I want the result FactSales(ID, qty_sold)

Ex, I have store_code values is 332.
But when I execute the process, not all record is success.
I already check both tables, Master Store and Sales DW have LEN(332) is 3.

Can you guys help me on this ?

Thanks
Henry

Comment: There is not enough information on the question to help you. Please provide table definitions and pictures of your dataflow and lookup component details.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your lookup transform join?

Comment: what is the datatype for every column?

Comment: `LEN(332) is 3` doesn't even make sense.   You're going to have to show screenshots of what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do Len(332), because Len(332) will give you 3 all the time. You should do Len(store_code) to check that '332' column, i am guessing there is space in column? or did you match the correct column between two tables?

BTW, when you mean error, what is the exactly error? cannot output or cannot compare?